# How to change the icon of an already existing .exe from c++?

Tags: c++, windows

Say that we have a hello world program on windows called hello.exe. Is it possible to create another program in c++ that changes the icon of hello.exe?

Answer (score 0):

External tools may help. For example ResHacker can modify resources in existing files (Windows PE format). Open the program in RH and replace a "Icon Group" with another `.ico` file and save it.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with ResHacker. It's just a tool I like.